# How to document kwargs using epytext for the auto completion hinting in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring, keyword-argument, epytext

Is is possible to get an additional hint for kwargs, which will give you examples of predefined possible keyword arguments? Maybe epytext is not supporting it?

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        @param name: Name
        @type name: str
        @param age: Age
        @type age: int
        @param connections: Connections to other persons
        @type connections: [Person]
        .
        .
        . # I know this is not working
        """
        self.name = kwargs[name] if name in kwargs
        self.age  = kwargs[age] if age in kwargs
        # and so on ...
```

Would be great if I'll get something like this in the completion hint (sorry I had to remove the pictures):

- > self,name,age,connections

Whith a Quick Doku looking like this:

- No image*

I really like to have global classes with common classes as parents. That makes it much easier for reuse. So here is a little snippet example:

```
class common():
    PERSON_DETAILS = dict( name       = ' ',
                           age        = 1,
                           connection = []  )
```

With a bit different defined class of Person:

```
class Person(common):

    def setDetail(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Set some detail information about the person.
        """
        argErrors = []
        for arg, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            if arg in self.PERSON_DETAILS:
                if type(value)==type(self.PERSON_DETAILS[arg]):
                    self.doSomething() # I don't want to go deeper here
                else:
                    raise ValueError("setDetails(%s) the type of '%s' needs to be %s, %s found" % (arg,arg,type(self.PERSON_DETAILS[arg]),type(value)))
            else:
                raise TypeError("setDetails() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" %arg )



person = Person()
person.setDetails()
```

The following (picture removed) shows what I get as completion hint (which is totally right), but it would be great to have a rolled out argument list from kwargs (like in the first example):

- > self,**kwargs

I know that the docstring implementation for definitions and auto completion hints are limited, but maybe someone knows a different way to get what I want in PyCharm.

Comment: The whole point of `**kwargs` is that you can pass *any arbitrary keyword arguments*. AFAIK you can only hint `@param kwargs` as a whole in `epytext`, otherwise it doesn't know what parameters you're referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the Epytext documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/fields.html), you will be able to achieve this by using `@keyword`.

> `@param` fields should be used to document any explicit parameter (including the keyword parameter). `@keyword`fields should only be used for non-explicit keyword parameters:

Also, `@kwarg p: ...` and `@kwparam p: ...` are synonyms.

Comment: "You need configured Python 2 SDK to render Epydoc  docstrings" Isn't there a standard way? I even tried copying docstrings from some classes but I'm not getting hints when I apply the docstring to my class methods